# spring bean optional property

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I am using a data source defined in tomcat in my spring configuration as shown in the below xml.

It can happen sometimes that this data source may not be defined in the context.xml of tomcat.
In such cases , the context initialization fails since myDS is not found.

Is it possible to configure the datasource as optional so that application initialisation is not impacted ? 
There can be a run time error when this data source is accessed , which is acceptable

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/myDS"/>
    </bean>

<bean id="myEntityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com..XX.XX" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU" />

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="#{systemProperties['showSql'] == null ? 'true' : systemProperties['showSql'] }" />
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="persistenceUnitPostProcessors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="wrkflw-punitpostprocessor" />
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">#{systemProperties['dbDialect']}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Thanks
Muhad

Answer (score 0):

You may check the `DelegatingDataSource`, you could encapsulate the logic to load the datasource from `JNDI` within its instantiation. For your application there will be always a `DataSource` there, but in some cases (whenever its not able to load the `DataSource` from `JNDI`) there is no delegation.

Comment: Is there any configuration which i can do in the xml .? I do not want to write a delegatehandler for this . SpringObjectFactory supports a default object in case if JNDI fails . I will try that .